# Rails file upload issue due to Phusion Passenger tmp folder rotation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ubuntu-12.04, passenger

I have a problem with a rails app running on a newly set up server. The rails app runs on ubuntu/ngnix/passenger.

- OS: Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
- Webserver: ngninx 1.5.4
- Passenger v 4.0.24

When uploading larger files through the rails app, when the upload finishes, the app throws a "502 Bad Gateway" error. This only happens for bigger files.

The error log from nginx looks like this:

```
2014/10/07 14:03:21 [crit] 24511#0: *339 connect() to /home/.../tmp_passenger/passenger.1.0.14062/generation-15/request failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: www.xxx.com, request: "POST /path HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger:/home/.../tmp_passenger/passenger.1.0.14062/generation-15/request:", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://www.example.com/path"
```

Now, when looking into the folder in `/home/.../tmp_passenger/passenger.1.0.14062/generation-15` the generation-N folder seems to be rotating exactly every 60 seconds from `.../generation-11` to `.../generation-12` and so forth.

Now, obviously any upload - for which passenger uses this generation-N directory as tmp – will fail if it takes longer than a minute, or hits this rotation by chance on shorter uploads.

Now, I really don't know where this rotating of the generation-N folders is happening/configured. I'm pretty sure this is what I need to fix this annoying issue.

From Googling I have the impression that either:

- systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service is responsible for the rotation. (but how to change the timing of 60 secs in that case?)
- or the respawning of passenger somehow invokes a rotation of the generation-N folder although the PID stays the same so I don't think it's a complete restart of passenger responsible here.